# Is this a termite? What bug has been eating my wood?

Tags: basement, pest-control, pest, termite

Replacing some drywall revealed something has been destroying the wood behind it. While removing things to see more, I saw 3 of these kind of bugs. I originally thought carpenter ants were the cause of the destruction.

Is the bug in the picture just a basement dweller that’s attracted to damp old basements? Or is it likely the cause of the wood damage?

FYI, it’s a 100 year old house in MN.

[image: pic of bug][image: pic of wood damage][image: pic of sawdust]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That most definitely appears to be termite damage. The pictured bug is NOT a termite however. It looks like what we call an "earwig" here in the south.

Comment: Phew thanks. Creepy little buggers. Now to call pest control about the termite damage...

Comment: We call that a "Silverfish". An earwig is something different that the kids call a "pincer bug", and they will pinch with their large foreceps.